Macbook Air a1466 early 2015: can I replace logic board from a newer model, to get 16 GB of RAM?
As I read, 8 GB is max for this model, such logic board price is around $140.
Now I have model with 4 GB, i5.
But I found a store review on AliExpress that shows 16 GB for that model:
Another photo from AliExpress description - they have differen photos for different years, but from 2013 to 2017 they have single photo - so it looks like I can replace to any year?


Just in case you're still wondering about upgrading the logic board, you can switch motherboards between 2013 to 2017 MacBook Air 13" A1466. All parts are compatible between them. Done that kind of upgrade several times and also used older parts to fix newer machines. 2012 or older parts are mostly not compatible with 2013 or newer.
At least later models can (technically) be upgraded to 16GB of RAM (look for Dosdude1 on YouTube), but it's really expensive and specialized work, only worth for collecting or some special use case. They were never oficially released by Apple with that amount of memory.

8GB RAM is the maximum
The maximum amount of RAM that the MBA could be configured with (at time of purchase) is 8GB.  The 2013 and 2014 MBA notebooks came with a standard 4GB of RAM with 8GB RAM option for $100USD at purchase.  Below is a table summarizing this data.



MBA model
Standard RAM
Maximum RAM




Mid 2013
4GB
8GB


Early 2014
4GB
8GB


Early 2015
4GB/8GB *
8GB


2017
8GB
8GB



* 4GB RAM was standard configuration until April 2016 when 8GB became standard
There was no MacBook Air model that was configured to 16GB
TL;DR

they [Ali Express] have different photos for different years, but from 2013 to 2017 they have single photo - so it looks like I can replace to any year?

You can’t go off the picture especially when they use stock images for their product descriptions.  Also, consider the vendor - Ali Express. They have quite a reputation for selling junk and for their 3rd party vendors misleading consumers with regards to the product capabilities
Since a 16GB MacBook Air never existed for those vintages, I would steer clear of this purchase
I recommend that you purchase a new(er) MacBook Air given that logic boards will be anywhere from 7 to 11 years out of date. The cost to repair versus getting a new unit makes a very strong case against this swap you’re looking to do.  After all, you may spend several hundred dollars to end up with an obsolete product in the end.
